using python to write class to print data for each employee
I am using python to write an Employee class so that I am able to print the data for each employee in the input.

I have to write a file titled employee.py that has a class called Employee and store the following attributes: name, ID number, department and job title

write a program named employee_test.py that creates three employee objects to hold the data

Ex: Susan Meyers, 47889, Accounting, Vice President


I tried the codes below but I ran into a module error and I checked to make sure it was installed as well. I was expecting to see the names printed out with their information.
class Employee
def __init__(self, name, id_num, dep, title):
    self.__name = name
    self.__id = id_num
    self.__dep = dep
    self.__title = title

def set_id(self, id_num):
    self.__id = id_num

def set_dep(self, dep):
    self.__dep  = dep

def set_title(self, title):
    self.__title = title
def __str__(self):
    result = f"{self__name}/t{self.__id/t{self.__dep}/t{self.__title}"
    return result

from employee import Employee 

def main():
    Susan = Employee("Susan Meyers", "47899", "Accounting", "Vice President")
    Mark = Employee("Mark Jones", "39119", "IT", "Programmer")
    Joy = Employee("Joy Rogers", "81774", "Manufacturing", "Engineer")

    print(Susan)
    print(Mark)
    print(Joy)

main()
   

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/19013/employee_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from employee import Employee
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'employee'


Unrelated note: Just name your attributes without leading __, and get rid of all the set_ methods. Idiomatic Python doesn't use setter methods unless the cost of setting is extremely high (when it's necessary to have setting occur programmatically, @property can be used, and would be accessed like an attribute, not using method calls).

Firstly:
You forget ":" end of Employee class.
Secondly:
result is wrong. it should be like that.
result = f"{self.__name}/t{self.__id}/t{self.__dep}/t{self.__title}"

Thirdly please check your if your employee.py and employee_test.py are in same location. I have tested and it worked.
I have checked and fixed problems in your code. Full code and output is like that:
employee.py will be like that.
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, id_num, dep, title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__id = id_num
        self.__dep = dep
        self.__title = title

    def set_id(self, id_num):
        self.__id = id_num

    def set_dep(self, dep):
        self.__dep  = dep

    def set_title(self, title):
        self.__title = title
    def __str__(self):
        result = f"{self.__name}\t{self.__id}\t{self.__dep}\t{self.__title}"
        return result

And this is employee_test.py
from employee import Employee 

def main():
    Susan = Employee("Susan Meyers", "47899", "Accounting", "Vice President")
    Mark = Employee("Mark Jones", "39119", "IT", "Programmer")
    Joy = Employee("Joy Rogers", "81774", "Manufacturing", "Engineer")

    print(Susan)
    print(Mark)
    print(Joy)

main()

This one that output.
Susan Meyers    47899   Accounting      Vice President
Mark Jones      39119   IT      Programmer
Joy Rogers      81774   Manufacturing   Engineer


From your Traceback, your filename is employee_test.py but you're attempting to import from employee. Your import statement should rather be:
from employee_test import Employee

You presumably have two files, one named employee_test.py and the other is where you have your import statement and the codes below it.
Note that if you have everything in the same employee_test.py file, then there's no need for the import statement.
Also get rid of the leading underscores. Your employee_test.py should look like this:
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, id_num, dep, title):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id_num
        self.dep = dep
        self.title = title

    def set_id(self, id_num):
        self.id = id_num

    def set_dep(self, dep):
        self.dep  = dep

    def set_title(self, title):
        self.title = title
    def __str__(self):
        result = f"{self.name}\t{self.id}\t{self.dep}\t{self.title}"
        return result

and your other file should look like this:
from employee_test import Employee 

def main():
    Susan = Employee("Susan Meyers", "47899", "Accounting", "Vice President")
    Mark = Employee("Mark Jones", "39119", "IT", "Programmer")
    Joy = Employee("Joy Rogers", "81774", "Manufacturing", "Engineer")

    print(Susan)
    print(Mark)
    print(Joy)

main()


Do you mean that employee_test should import itself?

i think OP has them in different files but got everything mixed up. He even included the traceback

I strongly suspect the OP intended for from employee import Employee to be the first line of a separate file, with the code above it in a separate file (presumably employee.py). This doesn't seem likely to be helpful.
